# How to detect and get information of table column encryption

Tags: sql-server, encryption

I'd like to make a query that checks for encryption and outputs all columns in a randomly given database table if they are encrypted.
So I want the output to look like this

```
Column Name   |   Encryption Key Name  |  Encryption Type  |  Algorithm Used
Baby Power         Key name for bp           Randomized       AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256
Diaper             Key name for Diaper       Deterministic    AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use following query:

```
SELECT 
    t.name AS TableName,
    c.name AS ColumnName,
    k.name AS KeyName,
    c.encryption_type_desc,
    c.encryption_algorithm_name
FROM sys.columns c
    INNER JOIN sys.column_encryption_keys k ON c.column_encryption_key_id = k.column_encryption_key_id
    INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE encryption_type IS NOT NULL
```

This will return all encrypted columns in current database. If you want only for specific table, add where condition with filter on `t.name`.

In general, if you want to find information about different database objects, system views under `sys` schema are the right place.

Answer (score 0):

At the table level, this will list out the columns and indicate which is encrypted with a bit.

```
SELECT 
    DB_NAME()                               AS [DB_NAME],
    T.[name]                                AS [TABLE_NAME],
    C.[name]                                AS [COLUMN_NAME],
    IIF(C.encryption_type IS NULL, 0, 1)    AS [ENCRYPTED]
FROM 
    sys.tables AS T
    INNER JOIN sys.columns AS C ON T.[object_id] = C.[object_id];
```